# How to view database created using Amnesia

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, mnesia

I'm very new to Amnesia and Elixir. I write a custom mix task,Mix.Tasks.PopulateDB, which just populate some test data to the Database, which I created use mix amnesia.create -d Database --disk, the Database is defined under my_app/database.ex using defdatabase and deftable ...

I can populate data to the database when I run mix PopulateDB and I test it by reading data from the Database and use IO.inspect to inspect the returned result. But I can not find any data when start my phoenix application which called Amnesia.start and query data from the Database. I also start erlang's observer:start() to view the database, but I can not find any table. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not personally used Amnesia, but since it is using erlang's mnesia, you should be able to see your created tables using `:mnesia.schema()`. See docs here http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#schema-0

Comment: I can saw the tables using :mnesia.schema, but they are all empty.